# PoDoFo: Print a Barcode to a pdf

Tags: c++, barcode, podofo

Has anybody experience with this?
I'm trying to print a barcode to a pdf. The solution to set the Code128 font works but i want to get the code from GNU barcode lib or another barcode lib.

I looked through the PoDoFo docs, but didn't find a feature that prints barcdes. Is there such a feature?

Comment: Would a [LaTeX solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6895/88563) work?

Comment: If you already have GNU barcode lib, why not use barcode lib and print to SVG, PS, EPS and then embed that in your pdf?